# Spring Cloud Data Flow 2.10.3 : may i launch a Task linked to a specific application version, instead of default version

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I'd like to run a Task (or create a new Task and run it) whom execution will trigger deployment and execution of a specified (on task level) version of the linked application.
I don't find how to do, i thought that i could use the TaskBuilder.definition() method and formulate a specific definition including version number. But i'm unable to find documentation about the DSL that's consummed by the builder and if it allows to specifiy a specific application version.

More accurate, my final objective is to be able to launch different version of the same application on the same scdf server instance (in order to mutualize multiples environment on the same scdf instance, to save resources and no more run as many scdf servers as environnements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this through dataflow.   First, register the versions of the application as shown here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-stream-lifecycle.
Note: It discusses streams but the same application registration steps are the same for streams and tasks.

Then at the time you launch your task, look for the `version` property under `Application Properties` on the launch page.  Select the version you want to launch.

Added issue to SCDF to enhance the docs to discuss this: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/5464

Comment: Thanks a lot. Effectively we can see the version property on ihm. But this information is missing in the documentation. I have searched after your reply and i'm still looking for. Also, "Applications properties are those properties that were created by the app developers to specify the behavior of the application." So it's illogical to set the application version to deploy in application properties. Perhaps, it should be a deployer properties, this is a little bit more logical as "Deployer properties are those properties that tell SCDF's deployer how the application should be launched."

Comment: i had misunderstood. This not an application property (aka app.<taskname>.version) but a version property (version.<taskname>). You were speaking about IHM where the version can be setted under the application section.